# How to simultaneously declare and initialize an expl3 integer variable

Tags: expl3

Is there a way to simultaneously declare and initialize an `expl3` integer variable?

Consider the following LaTeX code, which simultaneously declares and initializes a floating point variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_gset:Nn\myvar{1}
\fp_use:N\myvar
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

When this code is compiled with [Overleaf's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overleaf) 2022 [LuaLaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaTeX) engine, the compilation completes successfully and prints out `1`.

However, if now the two occurrences of the string "fp" are replaced by "int", and the code is recompiled, the following error message results:

```
<argument> \myvar

l.4 \int_gset:Nn\myvar{1}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but you're wrong. The instruction `\fp_gset:Nn` does not really declare the variable.

Indeed, if you run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_gset:Nn\myvar{1}
\fp_use:N\myvar
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

which is recommended during code testing, you will see that compilation stops with

```
! LaTeX Error: The variable \myvar has not been declared on line 5.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.5 \fp_gset:Nn\myvar{1}
```

By reasons of implementation, `\fp_gset:Nn` doesn't complain when the first argument hasn't been declared yet. The same happens for `tl`, `clist` or `seq` variables. But this doesn't mean that they don't need to be declared in advance: they *should* be anyway.

For integer variables it's a different thing, because they need to be assigned an internal register, so not declaring them in advance *always* produces an error.

Why the difference? Efficiency: overloading every `<var>_(g)set:Nn` function with the check about the variable being declared would slow processing too much.